# Метод генерации страниц php

Tags: php

На сайте работает система создания товаров.После заполнения определенных input'ов в бд отправляется запрос, создающий ячейку с описанием товара.После запроса при помощи fopen создается новый файл с названием, соответствующим переменной, полученной из input(название в input выглядит как название файла, например-product.php).Далее при помощи метода fwrite происходит запись в этот файл html кода, который возвращается из функции, в аргументы которой передаются переменные $name,$description.Функция возвращает html код, в котором уже записаны название и  описание товара, полученные из переменной в аргументе функции.Проблема в том, что код выглядит очень громоздким из-за функции, возвращающей весь html код страницы.Это правильная методика генерации страниц?Или код можно сделать короче?

Comment: А может вы приложите код?

Comment: ---На сайте работает система создания товаров.После заполнения определенных input'ов в бд отправляется запрос, создающий ячейку с описанием товара--- Вот до этого момента все ок. Остальные все манипуляции зачем? скрипт должен работать в связки php- mysql например. Все остальные танцы с бубном должны быть чем-то объяснимы.